# Proof that $\cos(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

Normally I just look up or remember that $\cos(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$, or type "$\cos(\pi/4)$" into WolframAlpha to check the answer.

But what about the **first time** someone wanted to know what $\cos(\pi/4)$ was? How could they find out before trig tables and WolframAlpha?

How can you prove that $\cos(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$?

Comment: Use $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x)-1$. On second thought. If this is for the first time then a geometrical explanations is probably best (see David's suggestion below)

Comment: Draw a $45^\circ$-$45^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle. Set the length of the hypotenuse to $1$. Solve for the other side lengths and calculate what you want.

Comment: is $\pi/4$ pronounced as "pi over four" or is it pronounced as "one quarter of half of a revolution"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a $45^\circ-45^\circ -90^\circ $ triangle.

Comment: What about $\cos(m\pi/n)$?

Comment: @john.abraham What are *m* and *n* there?

Answer (score 3):

we consider a isosceles right angled triangel and we have by definition
$\cos(\pi/4)=\frac{\frac{c}{2}}{a}$ and with $c=\sqrt{2}a$ we get
$$\cos(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

First of all 
$$\cos(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$$
therefore 
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$$
Secondly 
$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$
and thus
$$\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{4})+\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{4})=1\Leftrightarrow 2\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{4})=1\Leftrightarrow \cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=|\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}|$$
Since $\frac{\pi}{4}$ belongs to the first quadrant then 
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$